# AD user creation with SamAccountName availability check loop

Tags: powershell

I'm learning Powershell by making a script that will hopefully automate everything that needs to be done when we get a new hire or a consultant. Currently I'm working on the part that will create the AD account. Below are the variables specific to this portion of the script.

```
#Variables for preliminary SamAccountName, modifiers and initials array
$PrelSamAccountName = ("se" + [string]$GivenName.Substring(0,3) + [string]$SurName.Substring(0,3)).ToLower()
$Modifier1 = 1
$Modifier2 = 0
$InitialsArray = @("x","y","z")
```

Here is the loop. I cut out a bunch of parameters on New-ADUser to make it less cluttered.

```
try {
#Checks if preliminary SamAccountName is taken or not
$ADCheck = Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $PrelSamAccountName}
#Creates new user
New-ADUser -Name $Name -SamAccountName $PrelSamAccountName
} catch {
        #Replaces final character in preliminary SamAccountName with "1++"
        while (($ADCheck | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName) -eq $PrelSamAccountName) {
        $PrelSamAccountName = ([string]$PrelSamAccountName.Substring(0,7) + ($Modifier1++)).ToLower()
        }
        #Changes $Initials from $null to x/y/z if an existing user has identical name as new user
        while (($ADCheck | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name) -eq $Name) {
        $Initials = $InitialsArray[$Modifier2++]
        $Name = $GivenName + " " + $Initials + " " + $SurName
        }
    }
```

Everything is working as intended, except for the fact that a new user is created every other time I run the loop. Ideally I would want it to create a new user every time it is run. :)

I'm assuming it has something to do with the placement of the $ADCheck variable, but after having rewritten this portion multiple times I simply can't get it to work. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some logical problems in here:
Follow this Approach:

```
Pseudocode:
while (user exist) {create new username}
new-aduser new username
```

PS Code:

```
 function new-sam
 {
    #creates new sam
 }

 $sam = "username"
 $a=$false
 while (!$a)
 {
     try {
        $a = [bool](Get-ADUser -Identity $sam )
     }
     catch {
        $a = $false; $sam = new-sam
     }
 }
 new-aduser ....
```

Comment: Thanks, Martin. I've been reworking the code per your suggestion, I'll post it once I get it working.

Comment: OK, I got it working the way I want it now. I'm sure the code could be cleaner, but that's something for another day. Thanks again for your suggestion, Martin. I learned a lot by following your approach. :)

Code here: http://hastebin.com/ovavinaqun.mel

Comment: In your func $Integer is a bool-var. Use just if {} else {} for your return Statements, instead of while. The while-statement creates a loop based on a condition, where if just evaluates once. I also changed the try/catch block. Should exactly works the same. Modificication here: http://hastebin.com/opigepafan.mel